# Q: Limits of functions and sequences

Tags: real-analysis

I am having difficulty understanding this proof in Gaughan's Introductory Analysis text (p. 69 & 70).

$2.1\ Theorem$ 
Let $f: D \to R$ with $x_{0}$ an accumulation point of $D$. Then $f$ has a limit at $x_{0}$ iff for each sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converging to $x_{0}$ with $x_{n} \in D$ and $x_{n} \ne x_{0}$, the sequence $\{f(x_{n})\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges

**Pf**

$(\Leftarrow)$Suppose for each sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converging to $x_{0}$ with $x_{n} \in D$ and $x_{n} \ne x_{0}$, and the sequence $\{f(x_{n})\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges.  Then all sequences (subsequences(?)) of $\{f(x_{n})\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ have a common limit, called $L$.  Suppose on the contrary that $L$ is not a limit of $f$ at $x_{0}$.  That is, $\exists \epsilon >0\ \forall\ \delta >0 \exists x \in D$, with $0 < |x-x_{0}| < \delta$ and such that $|f(x)-L| \geq \epsilon$.   In particular, for each positive integer $n$, there is $x_{n} \in D$ with $0 < |x_{n} - x_{0}| < \frac{1}{n}$ such that $|f(x_{n}) - L| \geq \epsilon$.  But the sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \to x_{0}$ and is a sequence of members of $D$ distinct from $x_{0}$;  hence, $\{f(x_{n})\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $L$, contrary to the fact that $|f(x_{n})-L| \geq \epsilon > 0$ for all $n$.  Thus, $L$ must be a limit of $f$ at $x_{0}$

I would appreciate it if someone could help explain this proof.  I don't follow the contradiction.  Because $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \to x_{0}$ and is a sequence of members of $D$ distinct from $x_{0}$, then  $\{f(x_{n})\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $L$?

Where exactly do we arrive at the contradiction that $\{f(x_{n})\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically what we assume here, is that if a sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x_0$ (and $\forall n\in N$ $x_n\ne x_0$), then the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ also converges.

1. First of all, we should state that all sequences $\{f(x_n)\}$ **share the same limit**. proof:
   if not, and we have two sequences $x_n$, $y_n$ who converge to $x_0$, then we could build a sequence $z_n$ s.t. $z_{2n}=x_{2n}$, $z_{2n+1}=y_{2n+1}$.
   lim(f($x_{n}$)) = lim(f($x_{2n}$)) = lim(f($z_{2n}$)) = lim(f($z_{n}$)) = lim(f($z_{2n+1}$)) = lim(f($y_{2n + 1}$)) = lim(f($y_{n}$))
   Thus let L be that limit.
2. Now, as you wrote, if the claim isn't true, and the function doesn't converge to L at $x_0$, $\exists \epsilon >0\ \forall\ \delta >0 \exists x \in D$, with $0 < |x-x_{0}| < \delta$, and such that $|f(x)-L| \geq \epsilon$. now, we build a sequence $x_n$, s.t. $0 < |x_{n} - x_{0}| < \frac{1}{n}$ such that $|f(x_{n}) - L| \geq \epsilon$ (from the negative assumption, we know that there is a sequence like that).
   Obviusly, the sequence $x_n$ converges to $x_0$, and is distinct from $x_0$. From the assumption, we know that $f(x_n)$ converges, and from what we proved above in paragraph (1), the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to L.
   **But this is the contradiction** since we also assumed that $\exists \epsilon >0\ \forall n\ |f(x_{n}) - L| \geq \epsilon$, and thus cannot converge to L.

Comment: O.K.  $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_{n}) = L$ and so $|f(x_{n})-L| < \epsilon$ $\forall \epsilon > 0$. Then if we assume $f$ does not converge to $L$ at $x_{0}$ then we get the contradiction.  I think I got confused because it seems like there should be a direct proof...  it seems very round about.  But I understand it now.  Thanks!